# Is there a way to gamble using slot machines faster in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've reached level 38 and now I can't quickly gamble away all my cash because it used to get to 30-40k and a spin cost about 1k, and now I've amassed a million and a spin still costs ~1.2k and the machines are not very fast to begin with.

Is there a way to speed up the machines or a spot where there are more machines so I can run through them all without waiting for spinning to stop? Maybe I can spawn a row of slot machines using in-game cheat codes? I know I can give myself any items I like using save editors but that doesn't feel fair, so I want to find a faster way to do it (mostly) legitimately.

Answer (score 5):

### Multiple Slot Machines

First of all, as you yourself mentioned, the best way is to play multiple machines at once. However, I do not know of a spot with more than 2. These places have 2 slot machines:

- Moxxi's (in Sanctuary)
- Badass Crater Bar (Torgue DLC)
- Flamerock Refuge tavern (Tiny Tina DLC)

### Torgue Slot Machines

In the case of the Badass Crater Bar, there are 2 additional Torgue Slot Machines. So if you can spend Torgue Tokens as well, you can play a maximum of 4 machines here.
**Note:** The Torgue Slot Machines have different rewards than the normal ones!

### Multiple Players

As mentioned in the [wiki](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Slot_Machine), playing the slot machines is more efficient the more players are in your game - regarding money, Eridium and Torgue Tokens, because everyone in your group will get rewarded the same number of credits without splitting, thus raising the total net amount given to group.

### Level of Loot

Also note that the level of the loot inside the machines corresponds to the price of a game. You paying only 1.2k$ for a spin probably means that the possible loot you can get is underleveled for you. Slot machine levels usually increase with progress in the main story line.